# Requirements to create Adobe AIR application

Tags: apache-flex, air, flexbuilder

i am working with Flex for quite sometime. but i hadn't get any chance to even look at Adobe AIR platform. I am planning to do some personal softwares using AIR.

Provided the background that am an absolute zero in AIR, what all should I have in my system apart from Flex builder? And how fast i can learn AIR if I am pretty comfortable in Flex?

Regards,
Anoop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can quite literally use any Flex code in AIR - the most imminent differences are the root tag of the application that is WindowApplication and a wider selection of methods available. AIR is only a platform that your Flex runs on, not an alternative or anything.

After you have created a new AIR project, you may want to check the MyTest-app.xml (or whatever the name of your app) file in the src folder. This is where, for instance, some properties of the new window created by the operating system reside.

As for tools, you'll want to install the AIR runtime if you don't have it already, but apart from that and Flex Builder you're all set!

Answer (score 0):

You're in a good position to start developing AIR applications given your background in Flex. What you have to learn would depend on what you already know and the kind of application you are going to build. We can help you if you share more details about the app.

Some things you can look out for are the WindowApplication object, File systems i/o, SQLite database ops, windows/menus/task bars etc. Here's the basics for getting started with AIR app development in Flex: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/Part5_AIR_1.html